# How to save Date from DialogFragment into database

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I am using code to create DatePickerFragment from Android tutorial. After I pick date, I want to save it, with some other variable, into the database. How can I make it?

My main class: (btw. I would prefer to extract the class DatePickerFragment if possible)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    database = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
    });
}

 public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            database.insert(dateInserted, otherVariable);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are asking for SQLite code then I would say your question is too broad.  You could save your date as `yyyy-mm-dd` format into the database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, I know how to save it in SQLite, the problem is how, and where, I can insert picked date and some other variable into database.

Comment: you can do it in `onDismiss()` of your DialogFragment

Comment: @MHP Could you show me some example of how can i use this method?